# Can't get NSXMLParser data into textfield, menu item, or label

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxmlparser, nstextfield, nsmenuitem

I am using the code below to parse an online XML file.  When I run the application, my textfields are empty.  How do I extract the strings from the NSXMLParser and put them into IBOutlets such as textfields, menu items, or labels?

interface file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XMLCurrent : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSTextField *location;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *condition;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *degreesF;

    NSMutableString *xmlLocation;
    NSMutableString *xmlWeather;
    NSMutableString *xmlTempF;
}

- (void)fetchCurrentWeather:(id)sender;

@end
```

implementation file:

```
#import "XMLCurrent.h"

@implementation XMLCurrent

- (void)fetchCurrentWeather:(id)sender {

    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KCLT.xml"];

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"location"]) {
        xmlLocation = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"weather"]) {
        xmlWeather = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"temp_f"]) {
        xmlTempF = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    [xmlLocation appendString:string];
    [xmlWeather appendString:string];
    [xmlTempF appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"location"]) {
        [location setStringValue:xmlLocation];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"weather"]) {
        [condition setStringValue:xmlWeather];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqual:@"temp_f"]) {
        [degreesF setStringValue:xmlTempF];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Your code looks right, are you sure your `IBOutlet`s are properly connected?

Comment: Did you try stopping in the debugger to see that the outlets are not nil?

Comment: Build your program to run in the simulator, set a breakpoint on the line that says `if ([elementName isEqual:@"location"])` by clicking on the vertical bar to the left of your editor's text space, and run with breakpoints enabled. Once your breakpoint is hit, hover the cursor over `location` variable to see its value.

Comment: Are you sure your `fetchCurrentWeather` gets called then? Could you set a breakpoint at the beginning of that method to make sure that the `parse` gets called?

Comment: Just to check that your breakpoints work fine, set one in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your app delegate file. If that breakpoint does not get hit, something is wrong with your debugging environment.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ok, the breakpoint at `application:didFinishLaunching` in the AppDelegate works. Breakpoints in my XMLCurrent class do not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there could be two reasons of your problem:

1. You're parsing XML before the `viewDidLoad` was called, and that's why all your outlets are nil
2. You didn't connect them in Interface Builder.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my outlets are connected correctly. See my previous comment above.

Comment: So how would I go about implementing reason 1?

Comment: Thanks I got it working.  I replaced the `(void)fetchCurrentWeather:(id)sender` method with `(void)awakeFromNib`